# How to detect that a cell is swiped to its normal status with editActionsForRowAtIndexPath in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have added some actions to a cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let info = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Info") { action, index in
        // ...
    }
    info.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    return [info]
}
```

I want to detect when the user taps the cell (not the info button) so that it swipes back to its original position. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` does the job.

Comment: Is there a similar method for UICollectionView, when it is displaying in List mode? I need to perform an action after the animations of the swipe are complete but cannot find a comparable method.